# Missing one .js resource from .nuxt/dist/client folder after yarn build

Tags: laravel, apache, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, pm2

I'm trying to deploy my Nuxt project using apache and pm2.

The nuxt project will be the front-end, and it has a backend api that is on a different domain.
I got the virtual host setup fine, I can access the login page but for some reasons, it always returns a 404 on one .js file that's supposed to be generated after I ran `yarn build` inside .nuxt/dist/client folder.

Some odd thing that's worth noting though is that when I use an invalid API_URL, like if I use a non-existent url `https://xxx.xxx/api/1` instead of the correct url `https://xxx.xxx/api/v1`. The error will disappear after retrying `yarn build` and pm2 restart

Here's the error:
[image]

My setup:

- OS: Debian 11
- Server: Apache2 & pm2

My nuxt.config.js

```
    import colors from "vuetify/es5/util/colors";

export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    titleTemplate: "%s - " + process.env.APP_NAME,
    title: process.env.APP_NAME,
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en",
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" },
      { name: "format-detection", content: "telephone=no" },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }],
  },

  watchers: {
    webpack: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000,
    },
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      laravelPassport: {
        provider: "laravel/passport",
        endpoints: {
          userInfo: process.env.API_URL + "/me",
        },
        url: process.env.API_SERVER,
        clientId: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET,
      },
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: "/user/login",
            method: "post",
            propertyName: "data.access_token",
          },
          logout: { url: "/user/logout", method: "post" },
          user: { url: "/me", method: "get", propertyName: "data" },
        },
        token: {
          property: "data.access_token",
        },
        user: {
          property: "data",
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: "Bearer",
        autoFetchUser: true,
      },
      customStrategy: {
        scheme: "~/schemes/customScheme",
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: "/user/login",
            method: "post",
            propertyName: "data.access_token",    
          },
          logout: { url: "/user/logout", method: "post" },
          user: { url: "/me", method: "get", propertyName: "data" },
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: "Bearer",
        autoFetchUser: true,
      },
    },
    redirect: {
      login: "/",
      logout: "/",
      home: "/admin",
    },
  },

  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: ["~plugins/vue-api-query"],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify",
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios", "@nuxtjs/auth-next"],

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ["~/assets/variables.scss"],
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3,
        },
      },
    },
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    maxChunkSize: 300000,
    extend(config, ctx) {
      config.performance.maxAssetSize = 700 * 1024;
    },
  },

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_SERVER || "https://xxx.xxx",
    apiUrl: process.env.API_URL || "https://xxx.xxx/api/v1",
    headers: {
      common: {
        Platform: "web",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: So, `yarn generate` or `npm run build`? Quite different commands.

Comment: @kissu so sorry I meant yarn build or npm run build. I tried both, I tend to interchange the terms, I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: You need to use only one, `generate`for SSG and `build` for SSR.

Comment: @kissu, thank you so much for responding. When I said both, I meant I tried "npm run build" and "yarn build" separate times trying to deploy it.

Comment: Same, use either NPM or Yarn, not both at the same time or you can get some issues.

Comment: So, can you reproduce the issue locally? Or is it broken only in production?

Comment: That's the other thing. I can't reproduce it locally. and the issue also disappears when I use an invalid api_url.

Comment: Probably some caching issues so.

Comment: I already did npm cache clean --force but the same thing happens. When I use an invalid api_url, nuxt generates all the files, but when I use the correct one, the error comes back, only one .js file is not generated.

Comment: More of a generated hash on the built files, not the `node_modules`. So, your deployed app is probably not taking new updates into account.

Comment: what can I do to clear cache on the built files? So sorry I'm not really a pro when it comes to nuxt and I really appreciate you trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for answers for days, I couldn't find the solution to my problem.
Only to find out that it's a pm2 issue somehow stopping yarn to generate some files. It turns out that when I stopped pm2 processes, it was still running on the background.

Here's how you can check if you have the same problem:

1. Stop pm2 process with `pm2 stop --name` or `pm2 stop all` (if you have no other processes running)
2. Delete the process using `pm2 delete --name` or `pm2 delete all` (if you have no other processes running)
3. Run `pm2 ls` to confirm that there is no other process running
4. Log your current user out and login using a different user
5. Run `pm2 ls`. If there are still processes running, stop them.
6. Redeploy with `yarn build` and `pm2 start`